# Bleeding scroll bars on OSX Lion

Tags: html, css, osx-lion, scrollbar, modal-dialog

I have a problem with new OSX Lion render of scroll in Webkit surrounding.

It seems that when I open modal dialog window, scroll bar which should be in the background goes over it. Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Here is the image of the issue:

[image]

Comment: Ugh, looks nasty. Does this happen in Safari as well? What does Firefox do?

Comment: It happens in all WebKit browsers (including Safari). FF is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. Are you setting the overlay element to be the full width & height of the viewport? I would assume this would stop any interacting with any elements behind the overlay.